# looking to translate the page to another language. localization example of total js?.Does it translate the whole page/welcome message?

Tags: total.js

// Total.js translation file
// Created: 2014-12-18 10:32

// index.html

```
T80818744        : Titulok
T-52966915       : Ahoj svet!
T-1870230665     : Total.js je webový framework pre Node.js
```

// IMPORTANT: This line was created manually

> message          : Priame čítanie

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you write more details in the description?

Answer (score 1):

Total.js can translate only phrases wrapped in `@(TEXT TO LOCALIZE)`. First you need to define Total.js delegate `onLocale` which can set the language for each request:

```js
F.onLocale = function(req) {

    // req.query.*
    // req.cookie('cookie_name');
    // req.headers['*']

    switch (req.query.langauge) {
        case 'sk':
        case 'cz':
        case 'ru':
            return req.query.langauge;
    }

    return 'en';
};
```

- framework tries to find a resource file in the form `/resources/YOURLANGUAGE.resource`
- if the file exists then the framework applies localization
- otherwise the framework will use a default resource called: `default.resource` (if exists)
- otherwise the framework use the phrases defined in views

**How to create a resource file with localization?**

I have prepared great utilites for localization, just install Total.js framework as a global library from NPM: `$ sudo npm install -g total.js`

```sh
$ cd yourapp
$ totaljs --translate
```

Total.js terminal app will create `translate.resource` file. Localize this file and copy it to `/resources/YOURLANGUAGE.resource` and restart app. That's all.

- [Example](https://github.com/totaljs/examples/tree/master/localization-resources)
- [Documentation](https://docs.totaljs.com/latest/en.html#pages~Localization)